# Java Generic Class Test

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

Im trying to test a java generic class that i wrote, this is my test

```
public class BSTTest
{
    public void testInsert()
    {
        int height;
        BST<int> myTree = new BST<int>();
        myTree.insert(1);
    }

}
```

but when i compile i get the error of unexpected type, it says if found an int but requires a reference on the line of BST myTree = new BST(); what does that mean?

below are my Binary search tree and node class for reference

```
public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
    public Node<E> root;


    public BST()
    {
        root = null;
    }
    //insert delete find height
    public void find(E s, Node<E> n)
    {
        //empty tree, root is null
        if(n == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Item not present.");
        }
        //n is the node where s is, return n
        else if(n.getData().equals(s))
        {
            System.out.println("Item present");
        }
        //s is greater than n, look for s on the right subtree
        else if(s.compareTo(n.getData()) > 0)
        {
            find(s, n.getRight());
        }
        //s is less than n, look for s on the left subtree
        else
        {
            find(s, n.getLeft());
        }
    }

    public int height() 
    {
        int count;
        return count = height(root); 
    }

    private int height(Node<E> n)
    {
        int ct = 0;
        if(n == null)
        {

        }

        else
        {

            int left = height(n.getLeft());

            int right = height(n.getRight());

            ct = Math.max(left, right) + 1;
        }
        return ct;
    } 

    public void insert(E s) 
    {
        root = insert(s, root);
    } 

    private Node<E> insert(E s, Node<E> T)
    {
        //easiest case, empty tree, create new tree
        if(T == null)
        {
            T = new Node<E>(s,null,null);
        }
        //easiest case, found s
        else if(s.compareTo(T.getData()) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Item already present.");
        }
        //s is greater than T, insert on right subtree
        else if(s.compareTo(T.getData()) > 0)
        {
            T.setRight(insert(s, T.getRight()));
        }
        //s is less than T, insert on left subtree
        else
        {
            T.setLeft(insert(s,T.getLeft()));
        }
        return T;
    }

    public void delete(E d)
    {
    }

}
```

and my node class

```
public class Node<E> 
    {
       private E data;
    private Node<E> left;
    private Node<E> right;
    private Node<E> parent;

       public  Node(E d, Node<E> r, Node<E> l) 
    {
      data = d;

        left = l;
        right = r; 
       }
       public void setData(E d) 
    {
      data = d;
       }
    public E getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
       public Node<E> getRight() 
    {
      return right;
       }
    public void  setRight(Node<E> nd)
    {
        right = nd;
    }
       public Node<E> getLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }
    public void  setLeft(Node<E> nd)
    {
        left = nd;
    }
    public Node<E> getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }
    public void  setParent(Node<E> nd)
    {
        parent = nd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: +1 your answer is indeed correct. it'd be great if you add explanation thou

Comment: Thanks for comment.
int is primitive type and Integer is object. In java generic can't be primitive type, only objects.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type takes only Classes (Object types) and not the primite data type
It should be

```
BST<Integer> myTree = new BST<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java generics are only for Object types. Since, `int` is a primitive type you cannot use it. Instead use `BST<Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a primitive type like `int` as a parameter to a generic class in Java. It has to be a class type, such as `Integer`.